# Sequel gem reorder postgres database?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I'm using the Sequel gem with a postgres database which has a 300k+ entries. I'm trying to get the earliest and latest entry by time, however I migrated the db and some entries got out of order time-wise.

If I use `mydb[:items].first` and `mydb[:items].last` it takes a fraction of a second for the query. However, like I said, they aren't fully in order of time, so that can get messed up. If I run `mydb[:items].order(:time).first` and `mydb[:items].order(:time).last`, it works but it takes FAR longer (roughly six seconds) to complete each query.

Is there a way to reorder the database so it's naturally in order of time, so I don't have to run the order command? Or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get record in a specific order you must use an order clause. Most databases do not guarantee the order if no sort clause is provided.

You should index your table by the fields you will use to sort.

Comment: Could you clarify - do you mean I should recreate the table? Or are you talking about some function that exists?

Comment: No. No matter if you recreate the table, records will not be retrieved in order, unless you specify the order in the query (such as `order(:time)`). So the important thing is to index the database by the field used to get records in order. If you want your records sorted by time, you must have an index based on the time field. Is your table indexed by time?

Comment: I'm googling to try and understand what you mean - I'm not very experienced with databases, so I don't know what you mean by creating an index.

Comment: `CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name (column_name)`; In your case: `CREATE INDEX mydb_time_index ON mydb (time)` (assuming the table is called mydb and the column is called time, as your OP states).

Comment: Amazing. Okay thank you! Will try that now. Do I specify the index name instead of the time column from that point on or do I continue as normal?

Comment: You continue specifying the column name. The database knows there is an index for this column.

Comment: Here's a short explanation on ORDER BY with an index.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/indexes-ordering.html